# how to reset a requirejs module between unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

I have a JavaScript project which I want to observe the TDD methodology. I chose the karma framework and requirejs library for this and followed an example demonstrated in the karma docs [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html).

There is an example of one unit-test file, which is:

```
define(['app', 'jquery', 'underscore'], function(App, $, _) {

    describe('just checking', function() {

        it('works for app', function() {
            var el = $('<div></div>');

            var app = new App(el);
            app.render();

            expect(el.text()).toEqual('require.js up and running');
        });

        it('works for underscore', function() {
            // just checking that _ works
            expect(_.size([1,2,3])).toEqual(3);
        });

    });

});
```

The main problem with this approach is that there is no way to clear the App module for each test. So if there are some changes in the App (like closure variables changes etc.) in one `it` call, then they can affect other `it` call.

Could anyone suggest something on this? These are such popular tools, I can't believe no one ever ran into such a situation.

So, to recapitulate the question, I would like to ask for an answer for any of these more specific ones:

- is there any way to "reset" (clear) module in requirejs? (**actually, I suppose that there is no such a way, except reload all modules once again**)
- is there any better approach to run karma and requirejs, so that modules do not have any remains (side effects) of other tests (`it` function calls) on them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from Google I've found a solution to this. I cannot say that it is ideal, but it works at least and in each test a required module is in it's *pristine* state.

First, one need to have his `main.js` test file like this, it is almost the same as in the [docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html), except tests are not defined as modules and are not included as dependencies:

```
require.config({file
    baseUrl: '/base',
    paths: {},
    shim: {},
    deps: [],
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

In the main karma config must be present this (one need to adapt his own paths)

```
files: [
    {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false},
    'tests/unit/**/*.js'
],
```

And in the tests themselves we leverage *jasmine* async tests capabilities and *requirejs.undef* method for "clearing" a module (which *will reset the loader's internal state to forget about the previous definition of the module*, as it is stated in the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef)).

This method has one implication, that it will not reset other modules, which are already loaded and depend on the reset module, but this should not be a problem, if one writes his tests in a right way, that is he tests only one module (and may be some parent ones, from which the child inherits some behavior), so that it should not be hard to `undef` several modules at ones.

```
describe('Some/Module tests', function() {
    'use strict'
    var M

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        requirejs.undef('src/Some/GParentModule')
        requirejs.undef('src/Some/ParentModule')
        requirejs.undef('src/Some/Module')
        require(['src/Some/Module'], function(m) {
            M = m
            done()
        })
    })

    it('some description', function() {
        var i = 0

        for (var prop in M) {
            i++
        }
        expect(i).toEqual(1)
        expect(prop).toEqual('init')
        expect(M.init).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function))
    })
})
```

I've checked this, between `it` calls changes to the module do not persist, so I suppose, it's safe to use this approach.

Thanks everyone for help, if someone has a better way, please answer here.

Answer (score 2):

> - is there any way to "reset" (clear) module in requirejs?

You can use [`requirejs.undef()`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef), but the documentation mention some gotchas. And to my knowledge there is no call you can use to say "unload this module and everything it depends on", which in a complex application is probably what is needed.

> - is there any better approach to run karma and requirejs, so that modules do not have any remains (side effects) of other tests (it function calls) on them ?

The better approach is to design your application so that state is tied to an object you instantiate rather than to the *module* itself. This is what I do in the test suite for a large application of mine. The `beforeEach` hook resets what requires resetting and instantiates the application anew for each test.

Comment: thank you, but I cannot agree with your suggestion *to design your application so that state is tied to an object you instantiate rather than to the module itself*, because even if I did this (although I do not want do it this way), the problem persists, at least in JavaScript. Because of the fact that a module definition is a function, even if I instantiate an object I cannot depend on it as *clear* for every test (some closure vars can be changed at least).

Comment: It seems that I've found an acceptable solution, which I'm going to post as an answer below

Comment: @user907860 You must have some misconception about how JavaScript works because **it is quite doable**. As I said in my answer, I've done it.

Comment: could you please provide some code example? I mean that if you have only one require/define call for a module which you're testing in many `it` calls, then you cann't be sure (only if you do not intrude to the inner stuff of the module) that it's state is reset. Because, if I call a method on a module instance and it is something like this: `define(function() {var foo; return function() {this.method = function() {foo++}}})`. Then if I call `var ins = new Module; ins.method()` in one test, I will have this module with `foo += 1` in other test.

Comment: even if in other test (or in beforeEach) I call `var ins_2 = new Module` I will still have Module with it's inner foo variable incremented for 1

Comment: The example you give in your comment is doing *exactly* what I said *not* to do: *you are tying state to the module*. Make `foo` an *instance variable* and state will be tied to the *instance* rather than to the *module*.